# How to write a program that references to file, where the directory changes

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I'm currently working on a program that uses databases and all that kind of stuff for a friend of mine. Now while doing my basic planning of what I will need to do, I thought to myself how will I get the program to connect to the right MS Access database if I hard code the path to my own personal computer? Because ill be using pyinstaller to package the program for him.

Do I need to build the directory in a dynamic way that uses the path of the current script, and then some string manipulation of that path to get the right file?
i.e.

```py
import os
    
file_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
# Using prior knowledge knowing the file name length is 7
file_path = file_path[:-7]                        
#appending the path string to point to the database
file_path = file_path + "/databases/test.accdb"
```

Or will the program still someway find its way to that database?

Comment: If you can't guarantee that the file path won't change, the easiest workaround is to ask the user to give it to the program - either through the `input` function, a command-line argument or through a GUI.

Comment: Or a config file.

Comment: Does your app generate the dbs? Then it should be easy, because you know the logic. Of course you should program it relative to some base path, e.g. the location of the script, or a home directory, etc. Otherwise use config file(s) - see comment from Thierry.

Comment: I'm still deciding how I'll implement them based on the information I learn here, but creating the database within the code seems the best way for now. Don't know what a config file is but will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a: `os.walk(...)` function to locate specified name file or every database file in specified directories. Next user can choose which file is correct